# MAGMA hom function

Tags: abstract-algebra, magma-cas

Suppose I have two fields `E1` and `E2`. If I tell MAGMA to do:

```
isom:=hom<E1->E2|b^7
```

where `a,b` are the multiplicative generators of `E1` and `E2` deprived of their zeroes respectively, what do I get? A group homomorphism or a field homomorphism? And if the former, how do I get a field homomorphism instead? Does the `hom<|>` function build a group hom if given groups and a field hom if given fields? And if so, what does [this](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Software/magma/text306.html) mean when it says:

> Note that it is the responsibility of the user that the map defines a homomorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magma will simply use hom to give a mapping from E1 to E2 based on the generator images; not sure exactly how it gets all the images.  There is no need to worry about how it gets them, assuming the map you give actually determines a homomorphism.  It will be a field homomorphism if you give it fields.

However, Magma won't check that you have a homomorphism.  And if it's not, who knows what sort of map you will get; Magma will use a mystery algorithm to assign images to all elements of the domain (for a field, ensuring 1->1) and you will just have a map (I tried making a hom from $\mathbb{F}_{9}$ to $\mathbb{F}_{3}$ by sending a generator of $\mathbb{F}_{9}$ to $1$; the map I got out preserved addition but not multiplication).